# how to add column values directly with sql bulk in asp.net 4.0

Tags: c#-4.0, asp.net-3.5

i just want to add column values directly when importing all row details from Excel to Sql data base.

here are my code :

```
    protected void lbut_import_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (Page.IsValid)
            {
                if (FileUpload1.HasFile)
                {
                    if (FileUpload1.FileContent.Length > 0)
                    {
                        string Foldername;
                        string Extension = System.IO.Path.GetExtension(FileUpload1.PostedFile.FileName);
                        string filename = DateTime.Now.ToString("ddMMyyyy_HHmmss");
                        if (Extension == ".XLS" || Extension == ".XLSX" || Extension == ".xls" || Extension == ".xlsx")
                        {
                            Foldername = Server.MapPath("~/Files/");
                            FileUpload1.PostedFile.SaveAs(Foldername + filename + Extension);
                            String conStr = "";
                            switch (Extension)
                            {
                                case ".xls": //Excel 97-03
                                    conStr = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;" +
                                    "Data Source=" + Foldername + "//" + filename + Extension + ";" +
                                    "Extended Properties=Excel 8.0;";
                                    break;

                                case ".xlsx": //Excel 07
                                    conStr = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" +
                                    "Data Source=" + Foldername + "//" + filename + Extension + ";" +
                                    "Extended Properties=Excel 8.0;";
                                    break;
                            }
                            OleDbConnection excelConnection = new OleDbConnection(conStr);
                            OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand("Select * from [Sheet1$]", excelConnection);
                            excelConnection.Open();
                            OleDbDataReader dReader;
                            dReader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                            SqlBulkCopy sqlBulk = new SqlBulkCopy(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["CRMConnectionString"].ToString());
                            //Give your Destination table name
                            using (DataClassesDataContext db = new DataClassesDataContext())
                            {
                                sqlBulk.DestinationTableName = "tbl_Party_master";
                                sqlBulk.ColumnMappings.Add("Name",int.Parse(dReader[txt_col.Text.Trim()].ToString()));
                                sqlBulk.ColumnMappings.Add("type_id", int.Parse(dReader[txt_col1.Text.Trim()].ToString()));
                                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(txt_col2.Text.Trim()))
                                {
                                    sqlBulk.ColumnMappings.Add("Ownername", int.Parse(dReader[txt_col2.Text.Trim()].ToString()));
                                }
                                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(txt_col3.Text.Trim()))
                                {
                                    sqlBulk.ColumnMappings.Add("Ownermob", int.Parse(dReader[txt_col3.Text.Trim()].ToString()));
                                }
                                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(txt_col4.Text.Trim()))
                                {
                                    sqlBulk.ColumnMappings.Add("Room", int.Parse(dReader[txt_col4.Text.Trim()].ToString()));
                                }
                                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(txt_col5.Text.Trim()))
                                {
                                    sqlBulk.ColumnMappings.Add("Road", int.Parse(dReader[txt_col5.Text.Trim()].ToString()));
                                }
                                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(txt_col6.Text.Trim()))
                                {
                                    sqlBulk.ColumnMappings.Add("Area", int.Parse(dReader[txt_col6.Text.Trim()].ToString()));
                                }
                                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(txt_col7.Text.Trim()))
                                {
                                    sqlBulk.ColumnMappings.Add("City", int.Parse(dReader[txt_col7.Text.Trim()].ToString()));
                                }
                                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(txt_col8.Text.Trim()))
                                {
                                    sqlBulk.ColumnMappings.Add("Mobile", int.Parse(dReader[txt_col8.Text.Trim()].ToString()));
                                }
                                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(txt_col9.Text.Trim()))
                                {
                                    sqlBulk.ColumnMappings.Add("Email", int.Parse(dReader[txt_col9.Text.Trim()].ToString()));
                                }
                                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(txt_col10.Text.Trim()))
                                {
                                    sqlBulk.ColumnMappings.Add("ContactPerson", int.Parse(dReader[txt_col10.Text.Trim()].ToString()));
                                }
                                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(txt_col11.Text.Trim()))
                                {
                                    sqlBulk.ColumnMappings.Add("ContactPersonmob", int.Parse(dReader[txt_col11.Text.Trim()].ToString()));
                                }
                                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(txt_col12.Text.Trim()))
                                {
                                    sqlBulk.ColumnMappings.Add("UserOFC", int.Parse(dReader[txt_col12.Text.Trim()].ToString()));
                                }
                                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(txt_col13.Text.Trim()))
                                {
                                    sqlBulk.ColumnMappings.Add("UserVAT", int.Parse(dReader[txt_col13.Text.Trim()].ToString()));
                                }
                                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(txt_col14.Text.Trim()))
                                {
                                    sqlBulk.ColumnMappings.Add("UserINV", int.Parse(dReader[txt_col14.Text.Trim()].ToString()));
                                }
                                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(txt_col15.Text.Trim()))
                                {
                                    sqlBulk.ColumnMappings.Add("UserNone", int.Parse(dReader[txt_col15.Text.Trim()].ToString()));
                                }
                                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(txt_col16.Text.Trim()))
                                {
                                    sqlBulk.ColumnMappings.Add("state_id", int.Parse(dReader[txt_col16.Text.Trim()].ToString()));
                                }
                                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(txt_col17.Text.Trim()))
                                {
                                    sqlBulk.ColumnMappings.Add("country_id", int.Parse(dReader[txt_col17.Text.Trim()].ToString()));
                                }
                                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(txt_col18.Text.Trim()))
                                {
                                    sqlBulk.ColumnMappings.Add("Remark", int.Parse(dReader[txt_col18.Text.Trim()].ToString()));
                                }
                                sqlBulk.ColumnMappings.Add("Register_Date", "Register_Date");
                                sqlBulk.ColumnMappings.Add("User_id","User_id");
                                sqlBulk.WriteToServer(dReader);
                                excelConnection.Close();
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    ibtnimexls_ModalPopupExtender.Show();
                }
            }
        }
```

i have found error like this :

```
1

Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 

Exception Details: System.IndexOutOfRangeException: 1

Source Error: 


Line 3015:                        {
Line 3016:                            sqlBulk.DestinationTableName = "tbl_Party_master";
Line 3017:                            sqlBulk.ColumnMappings.Add("Name",int.Parse(dReader[txt_col.Text.Trim()].ToString()));
Line 3018:                            sqlBulk.ColumnMappings.Add("type_id", int.Parse(dReader[txt_col1.Text.Trim()].ToString()));
Line 3019:                            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(txt_col2.Text.Trim()))

Source File: f:\CRM\Staff\Raise_Ticket.aspx.cs    Line: 3017 

Stack Trace: 


[IndexOutOfRangeException: 1]
   System.Data.ProviderBase.FieldNameLookup.GetOrdinal(String fieldName) +5002922
   System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataReader.GetOrdinal(String name) +68
   System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataReader.get_Item(String name) +15
   Staff_Raise_Ticket.lbut_import_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) in f:\CRM\Staff\Raise_Ticket.aspx.cs:3017
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.LinkButton.OnClick(EventArgs e) +118
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.LinkButton.RaisePostBackEvent(String eventArgument) +113
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.LinkButton.System.Web.UI.IPostBackEventHandler.RaisePostBackEvent(String eventArgument) +9
   System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(IPostBackEventHandler sourceControl, String eventArgument) +13
   System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(NameValueCollection postData) +176
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +5563

Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319; ASP.NET Version:4.0.30319.1
```

i don't know how i'm wrong here.........................

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [`SqlBulkCopyColumnMapping`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlbulkcopycolumnmapping%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) class only maps source columns to destination columns. Not source *values* to destination columns. (Note that you're even trying to map a source column to a destination value, which is hard to imagine).

You'll have to make sure the `dReader` has the required values hard coded in its query.